# Errors when trying to compile Android

Tags: android, compiling, libraries, error-handling

Here's my error, any help would be greatly appreciated:

```
 libcore/luni/src/main/native/Register.cpp:36: error: undefined reference to 'register_android_system_OsConstants(_JNIEnv*)' 
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) make: *** [/home/jukie/android/system/out/host/linux-x86/obj32/lib/libjavacore.so] Error 1
```

I'm on Ubuntu 14.10, building Android Lollipop cm.

Comment: Some more information would attract some people maybe like what software are you using that makes this error. What's the code you're using etc etc. with just the text you've put there no one will be interested in helping you but giving this question a -1 instead.

Comment: I thought i did... I'm using cm-12 source code on Ubuntu 14.10, everything else compiled fine until here and this was the is  only error to come out. Is there something else you wild like to know?

Comment: I have the same issue. Is it resolved ?